# MySQL 5.1.32-community and JDK 1.6.0_16

Tags: mysql, java-6, socketexception

I have this real weird exception when issuing a basic SELECT, using MySQL 5.1.32-community from JDK 1.6.0_16 code. The conditions to repeat : at any place in my app, if i change the date of my OS (WindowsXP SP3) and after that hit some refresh button, that is reloading info from database, while doing this multiple times (usually 2-3 times are enough) i get this error:

```
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2537)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setTransactionIsolation(ConnectionImpl.java:5148)
```

followed by some of my own code, and continued by this :

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    ... 128 more
```

Now, i have already google it and i found zero solutions. I have already tried using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" with no results. Also, i was able to test this on MySQL 4.12 and JRE 1.4 and the problem is inexistent there. I am using plain JDBC, single connection to DB (not pooled connections) and my SQL tables are using InnoDB type.
 Any help will be highly appreciated as i am pretty stuck there by this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, the driver uses the OS time to time out a connection or network operation.

The workaround is likely just to catch the exception and retry setting up the connection.

Comment: Hmm..can it be that simple? How should i retry that? By closing the current connection and re-initiate?